# Custom GMail CSS Prevents Click

Tags: css, gmail, customization, stylish

I am using [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) and the below CSS to customize the [Multiple Inboxes Lab](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/02/new-in-labs-multiple-inboxes.html) such that instead of the inboxes being in 1 vertical column, they are now in 2 columns with the first inbox taking over the top. The CSS does indeed work to give me the look I want.

However, for some reason I cannot discern, I am no longer able to click the emails within the inboxes. Thoughts as to why? Or how I can fix it?

```
/* example look */
| First Inbox |
| 2nd  | 3rd  |
| 4th  | 5th  |

/* each inbox */
.BltHke.nK {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 1%;
}

/* first inbox */
.nH.nn > .nH > .nH:first-child > .BltHke {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You may be covering up the click targets and/or Google may be doing evil things to the pages (again).  Try setting those 2 selectors to `z-index: 0;` (or 1) and make sure the click targets have a higher index. ...  May need a userscript for this.   ... The `width: 100%;` may be the culprit.  Try to think of another way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. That helped a lot!

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Brock Adams' hint, I figured out that pieces of the lower (or original) inbox were covering up the multiple inbox space due to my `float: left` rules.

To fix it, I had to float those pieces as well with the following code.

```
/* fix float over multiple inbox area */
.D.E.G-atb.bP {
    float: left;
}

.ae4.UI {
    float: left;
}
```